# How do I change iTween values at runtime?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I am trying to figure out how to run and change the speed of rotation on an iTween path at runtime. I'm trying to code it in Unity5 in C#. I have to rotate a few objects on an iTween path which I have created and I have to manage the speeds of the objects at runtime as they change.

**My problem is that:**
If I write the code in start method then it runs once within the whole game. How can I use this script in Update method so I can manage the speeds at the run time?

Comment: Could you please provide more information? The problem is unclear.

Comment: There is one path which I have created by iTween onto which an object runs at a constant speed but I have to manage the speed at run time as it is a betting game so for that I have to change the speed at the run time and it has to execute in update method because in start method the speed at the run time can not be updated. So for that how can overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a bool and a float to say when it should update?
For example, when the animation should start, make the bool True. After it's executed, make it false. Also change the speed to the float.

Comment: I don't know what to do with this game.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is to change the speed of an ITween animation on runtime, you can place the object on the path manually.

```
float speed = 1;
float distance = 0;
Vector3[] path;
float pathLength;

void Start()
{
    path = iTweenPath.GetPath("path_name");
    pathLength = iTween.PathLength(path);
}

void Update()
{
    distance += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float percentage = distance / pathLength;
    iTween.PutOnPath(gameObject, path, percentage);
}
```

You can now modify the `speed` variable on runtime, which alters the speed of movement along the path.